# Entity Framework 6: Delete entity with many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I have following entities

```
public class Entity1
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Entity3> Entities3 { get; set; }

   public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Entity3> Entities3 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity3
{
   [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
   [ForeignKey("Entity2")]
   public int Entity2_Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Entity2> Entities2 { get; set; }

   [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
   [ForeignKey("Entity1")]
   public int Entity1_Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Entity1> Entities1{ get; set; }

   [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
   public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to delete Entity1 this way:

```
private void DeleteEntity1(int id)
{
   var ent1 = dataContext.Entities1.Include(x=>x.Entities3).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
   var entities3 = ent1.Entities3.ToList();
   foreach(var entity3 in entities3)
   {
      entity3.Entities2.Clear();
      entity3.Entities1.Clear();
      dataContext.Entities3.Remove(entity3);
   }
   dataContext.Entities1.Remove(entity);
   dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

`dataContext.Entites1` is `DbSet<Entity1>` and similar `dataContext.Entities3` is `DbSet<Entity3>`.

If Entity1 exists without any relationship to Entity2 and Entity3 I'm able to delete Entity1.

But if Entity3 exists then dataContext.SaveChanges throws an exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error
>   occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships.  The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception.  Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.  See
>   the InnerException for details.'

Inner exception:

> OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete
>   statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have
>   been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Inner exception has one `StateEntries` of type `RelationshipEntry`:
`EntitySet: Entity3_Entity2`

Not sure how to delete Entity1 properly.

Comment: Delete all entries connected to Entity1. Entity1 should also have references to entites tied to it, so, take connected objects and delete them.

Comment: you should have specified all this in `CASCADE` in entity configurations

Comment: I've tried to specify cascade delete in entity configurations. In database I can delete Entity3 but if with EF I still have the same Exception.